# Can't use user id in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have been registering user ids, and when we go to Audience->User Explorer, the users are all there, each with their activity measures. But we can't find a way to filter some users out of our custom reports.
We do `ga('set', 'userId', 'xxxx-xxxx');` but we didn't create any custom dimension. We just told GA specific user-IDs for each.
We haven't been able to set up a segment, as we can't find the id in the filter. Neither in report filter.
We could go the the user and delete all their data. But that is not our point, and we need to keep this data as well. Ideally we would segment our users, but we can't use this filter in the segment definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to segment user by userID, you need to create a custom dimension of which you can access. The clientId is not accessible as a dimension to segment on.

Comment: Ok, So i have to set up a custom dimension with the same name as user-id? or I have to send  to GA the user-id( like we've been doing), plus the same string as a custom dimension? In any case, I won't be able to segment the data with the structure I have now? doesn't seem to make sense as the necessary information is there.

Comment: You can do just custom dimension or both. Still sending in user id will allow you do cross-device reporting. Though note if you do both, you’ll have to make sure every user has a value for user id.